# LINQ query with distinct count

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to construct a LINQ query in C# that will give me a list of distinct values from a column in a dataset with a count for each row.  The results would look like this.

```
State   Count
AL       55
AK       40
AZ       2
```

Here is the SQL that does that.

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM architecture arch
  GROUP BY name
  ORDER BY name
```

I've figured out the LINQ to get the DISTINCT values which is.

```
var query = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(dr1 => dr1.Field<string>("state"))
    .Select(dr1 => new {state = dr1.Field<string>("state")})
    .Distinct().ToList();
```

But I can't figure out how to get the COUNT(*) for each distinct value to work in LINQ.  Any idea how I can add that into the LINQ query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to group your results based on `State` and the Select count from the group like:

```
var query = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("state"))
            .Select(grp => new 
                            { 
                                state = grp.Key, 
                                Count = grp.Count()
                            })
            .OrderBy(o => o.state)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Missing ordering, but beat me :)

Answer (score 2):

Group all rows by value of *state* column. Then order groups by grouping key. And last step - project each group into anonymous object with grouping key (state) and count of rows in group:

```
var query = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
              .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("state"))
              .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
              .Select(g => new { State = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
              .ToList();
```

Query syntax will look like (I'll skip converting to list, to avoid mixing syntaxes):

```
var query = from r in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            group r by r.Field<string>("state") into g
            orderby g.Key
            select new {
                State = g.Key,
                Count = g.Count()
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with `Distinct`, when you can translate your SQL query to LINQ almost word-for-word? You can do it like this:

```
var query = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(dr1 => dr1.Field<string>("state"))
    .Select(g => new {
        State = g.Key
    ,   Count = g.Count()
    })
    .OrderBy(p => p.State)
    .ToList();
```

This produces a list of  `{State, Count}` pairs. If you prefer a dictionary of state-to-count, you can change your query like this:

```
var query = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(dr1 => dr1.Field<string>("state"))
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: I think you need `AsEnumerable()` for `DataTable`

Comment: @NewHire You're right, his `dr1.Field<string>("state")` may be incompatible with `IQueryable<T>`. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: I think that's what was throwing me off thinking I needed Distinct in there.  Thanks.

Comment: @John81 In general, `Distinct()` is a way to avoid using a more powerful `GROUP BY` when you don't need the full power of grouping. If you need distinct results, but `Distinct()` is insufficient, chances are that `GroupBy()` would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need GroupBy

```
var query = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
              .GroupBy(dr1 => dr1.Field<string>("state"))
              .Select(g => new {state = g.Key, count = g.Count())
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
              .GroupBy(x=>x.Field<string>("state"))
              .Select( g => new{
                   state = g.Key,
                   count = g.Count()
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess what, the equivalent of `group by` is `group by` :)

```
        var query = from dr1 in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                    group dr1 by dr1.Field<string>("state") into state
                    select new { State = state.Key, Count = state.Count() };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var stat = from row in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
group row by new
{
  Col1 = row["Name"],
} into TotalCount
select new
{
  ActionName = TotalCount.Key.Col1,
  ActionCount = TotalCount.Count(),
 };
```